# Rails, Javascript is not being deferred

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube-api, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-6

I ran a https://gtmetrix.com/ report and this came up..

1.2MiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.

```
https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-abcdefg/en_US/base.js (1.0MiB)
https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfll7K9A4/www-embed-player.js (93.7KiB)
https://js.stripe.com/v3/fingerprinted/js/shared-sdffdw93f1d62sdfsc3f9055e6e24f.js (64.3KiB)
https://js.stripe.com/v3/fingerprinted/js/controller-sdf67c5deede4sdfdc72aa.js (45.2KiB)
https://www.youtube.com/embed/novideoid?controls=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com&widgetid=1 (3.1KiB of inline JavaScript)
```

In my header file, I have..

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', :defer => "defer" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api', :defer => "defer" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ABCDEFG&libraries=places", :defer => "defer" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', :defer => "defer" %>
</head>
```

What is wrong that my scripts are not being deferred?

Rendered:

```
<head>
  ... code..

  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-abcdefg.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload">
  <script type="text/javascript" id="www-widgetapi-script" src="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-abcdefg/www-widgetapi.js" async=""></script><script src="/assets/application-abcdefg.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload" defer="defer"></script>
  <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api" defer="defer"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=abcdefg&amp;libraries=places" defer="defer"></script>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" data-turbolinks-track="reload" defer="defer"></script>

 <!-- I believe the below gets inserted by the code above, but I may be wrong --> 
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/40/1/common.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/40/1/util.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttps%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2F&amp;abcdefg&amp;callback=_xdc_._abcdefg&amp;key=abcdefg&amp;token=51011"></script>

</head>
```

## UPDATE:

Makes no sense, I moved the scripts to just above the body tag...

#### layout

```
<html lang="en">
    <%= render 'layouts/head' %>
    <body id='homepage'>  
        <%= render 'home/home_navbar' %>
        <%= render 'home/home_header' %>    
         <%= yield %>
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/head_defer' %>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### _head_defer.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api', defer: true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=abcdrfg&libraries=places", defer: true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>
```

The scripts render at the bottom, but I still get the issue above:

> 1.2MiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.

#### WHAT IS GOING ON?!!!

Comment: What is it rendering instead?

Comment: Can you expand on your question? rendering what? I added the defer: defer to my javascript tags, but when I run gtmetrix.com/ report it shows it's not being deferred. Let me know how to check what you want, and I will.

Comment: What's the output of the HTML in your view showing when you peak at the source?

Comment: @JoshBrody see above, I added the render

Comment: Everything appears to be rendered correctly; per your comment in your rendered HTML, that's likely injected via Google Maps.

Comment: Hence why I am confused by the error in the report

Comment: Rails and (CSS, JS) is nightmare for me always. These days, i prefer React and Rails API more reliable and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Common technique to defer javascript parsing even in very old browsers that do not support `defer` - is to move the `javascript_include_tag` to the very end of page, just above `</body>`.

When when using this method - include `<link rel="preload" href="yourfile.js" as="script">` for corresponding scripts, so that browser can start fetching before page is parsed.

Comment: Took your advice, still no luck